# Nosql Java cache extension?

Tags: java, caching

I've been reading more about the Java cache and been wondering if one could extend it with a nosql system so that java apps across multiple systems can have a common cache; ie 10 app servers all running the same app on a distributed architecture behind a proxy could share a common java cache stored on a nosql system like memcached.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Cache API only defines a technology-agnostic API to access a cache from a Java application.

The main implementations are EHCache, JBoss TreeCache and a few other, but I fail to see why it wouldn't be possible to implement an adapter to use MongoDB, memcached or any other NoSQL database.

So technically, yes, it should be doable. But the API is still relatively new, so maybe those adapter will be implemented soon by your favorite database provider.

See here for the existing implementations : [JSR 107 implementations](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/implementations/jsr107/index.html)

Comment: Yeah as I'm looking over this I realized this would make a great tool. May be my next project

Answer (score -1):

This is certainly a viable architecture approach. You might want to check out this article that provide a bit more details on how distributed caching can help distributing Java application:

http://www.cacheonix.org/articles/How_to_Distribute_Java_Application_on_Multiple_JVMs.htm